# Клиент серверный диалог

Tags: c#, .net, клиент-сервер, tcp-ip

Вопрос по `TcpClient`. Например, один `TcpClient` отправляет какое то сообщение другому. Тот в это время ждет данные при помощи `theClient.GetStream().Read(...)`. То есть когда данные приходят, он их считывает. Ну размер сообщения может отличаться от размера буфера, поэтому можно положить это в цикл и накопить байтики для последующей десериализации.

**Теперь вопрос.** Клиент и сервер осуществляют диалог (запорс/ответ) асинхронно. Может ли получиться так, что theClient на одной стороне при помощи цикла и `theClient.GetStream().Read(...)` примет в один массив байт байты от разных сообщений?

**UPD:**
Прочитал свой вопрос и понял, что могут возникнуть непонятки. :)

Поясню на примере.

С одной стороны асинхронно уходит 2 сообщения:

- "первое сообщение"
- "вторая строка"

На принимающей стороне срабатывает `theClient.GetStream().Read(...)` (и повторяется пока приходят данные). Не засунет ли такая конструкция две этих строки в одно сообщение?

**UPD2:**

Если я правильно понимаю, TCP пакет выглядит как то так

| HEADERS | BODY | END |

Так вот я в этой абстракции могу управлять только блоком BODY. Но этот блок может быть больше, чем размер пакета. То есть если я отправлю асинхронно 2 сообщения:

| HEADERS | ПЕРВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ | END |

| HEADERS | ВТОРОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ | END |

То на принимающей стороне это может выглядеть так

| HEADERS | ПЕРВОЕ  | END |

| HEADERS | ВТОРОЕ  | END |

| HEADERS | СООБЩЕНИЕ | END |

| HEADERS | СООБЩЕНИЕ | END |

И как это разруливать?

**UPD3:**

То, что данные придут в том порядке в котором они были отправлены, это я понимаю, но откуда мне знать, что в двух асинхронных потоках они отправятся именно так, как нужно? А нужно, чтобы было так:

Не важно в каком порядке отправятся сообщения, важно, что если они будут делиться на части, эти части не будут вокруг частей другого сообщения.

Comment: В TCP нет сообщений. Там есть один непрерывный поток байт. Протокол, который будет разделять этот поток байт на сообщения, Вам надо изобретать самому или найти уже существующий, который Вам подходит.

Comment: @PetSerAl, я примерно так и подумал, но решил уточнить. Может, посоветуете решение? Нужен именно велосипед. Я ведь не создаю пакет TCP самостоятельно. Я при помощи theNetworkStream.Write() отправляю данные. Я мог бы в данные воткнуть кроме тела еще и Id сообщения, но я не уверен даже, что сообщение придет одним пакетом. То есть сначала придет Id и часть сообщения, затем придет вторая часть сообщения. Как я могу понять, к какому отправленному сообщению относятся входящие данные, полученные при помощи Read?

Comment: @PetSerAl, прочитайте UPD2 пожалуйста

Comment: Не надо Вам рулить никакими пакетами. На уровне абстракции, с которым Вы работаете, вообще никаких пакетов нет. Есть только поток байт. TCP гарантирует, что данные из этого потока будут прочитаны в том же порядке, в котором были записаны. *Как разделять поток байтов на отдельные сообщения?* Наверное самый простой вариант: сначала писать длину сообщения, а потом само сообщение, таким образом Вы будете знать сколько именно байт нужно прочитать.

Comment: @PetSerAl, а как же асинхронность? :(

Comment: А что не так с асинхронностью?

Comment: @PetSerAl, если в двух потоках будет выполняться stream.Write(), то что окажется в потоке? Нужна ли блокировка? А если будет блокировка, то что толку от потоков? На MSDN информации очень мало и я боюсь стать жертвой дырявых абстракций. Ведь чтобы создать архитектуру протокола-обертки, мне нужно четко понимать, как работает в .net TcpClient, иначе я рискую переписывать все заново и ни раз

Comment: *если в двух потоках будет выполняться stream.Write()* Нельзя так делать. Метод `Write` не потокобезопасный и не может вызываться в двух потоках одновременно. *Нужна ли блокировка?* Нужна синхронизация, чтобы две операции записи не выполнялись одновременно. Синхронизацию можно получить и с минимальной блокировкой.